# Graphing trigonometric functions in degrees in Android

Tags: java, android, trigonometry

I have a graphing calculator app that can graph basic trig functions like sin and cos, and the user can specify if he wants it in radians or degrees. My question is how do I perform tangent, cotangent, etc functions in degrees? I know I'd have to use Math.cos() and Math.sin() in combination somehow in a formula but then how would I convert it to degrees? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doesn't [toRadians](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#toRadians%28double%29) <==> [toDegrees()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#toDegrees%28double%29) work ?

You can use these methods to convert from degrees to radians and the other way around